# SSRS - expand rectangle with tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a rectangle and a tablix inside. Is it possible to expand the rectangle along with the tablix height? If yes, how? I would like the rectangle to grow its height with the tablix without the tablix going over the rectangle border.

[image]

Comment: The rectangle should expand with whatever is inside it. Just make sure that you **drag and drop the table in the rectangle**.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the tablix and look in properties. If the Parent shows anything other than the name of the rectangle, then drag the tablix out and back again until it does.